# How to upload in app purchase to app store connect

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, storekit

Might come off as a stupid question, but how do I actually submit an in-app purchase to the App Store? I have a StoreKit Configuration file, and I have edited the Scheme to include it when I was testing the IAP.

[image]

[image]

Now my question is, do I have to remove the storekit file before uploading it to AppStore Connect? What are the next steps I should take to make it available? Thanks

Comment: The config file is for testing, it doesn’t get uploaded anywhere. You have to go to App Store Connect and add the purchases manually, then submit for approval with a build. There are many tutorials out there.

Comment: Gotcha, so I can just submit the app like I would normally right now through Xcode? I've already added the IAP details on App Store Connect, just wanted to confirm that it will all work once its launched

Comment: Just make sure they are ready for review and not awaiting metadata, it is something that is commonly overlooked. Also test using TestFlight, online, offline, etc